# How spring boots works ,How it loads all the configuration

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, restful-architecture

So I am having my rest Api calls using spring boot.
I want to know how spring boot loads all the configuration step by step.
like what would be the process while loading configuration,what and how the order are getting followed. Spring security,db configuration and bean initialization in term of all How these are getting loaded. 
And how the spring boot find the priority (order) ,which should be loaded first and which should be next.

Comment: `@Order(int value)` define order for load. the lowest the value, loaded first. Before asking this type of question you should read documentation first. If you can't understand something from the doc, then you can ask which part/portion you don't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beans are loaded based on the autoconfiguration mechanism in Spring Boot, there is a `spring.factories` file in the `META-INF` folder of the jar file containing the the fully qualified name of the Configuration classes to load.
When Spring Boot finds a file like that, it will load the configuration as a bean, and the configuration usually loads other beans.

Other way configuration could be loaded, by just simply `@Import`ing them, some work like that, example `@EnableMetrics`.

Jar files containing this autoconfiguration mechanism usually called starters.

There are some special beans as well that will be picked up by Spring, example FilterDefinitionBean that will be turned into a filter, or CommandLineRunner, that will be executed after startup.

---

Usually you do not need to worry too much about the order of the starters, since Spring Boot automatically detects the correct order to initialize these based on the dependencies, beans with `@DependsOn` annotations.
Spring Boot starter autoconfiguraions happen after your beans are already defined, so they can give you fallback beans, but only if you have not defined them.

But sometimes, especially when you have `@ConditionalOnBean` you have to explicitly define the order, this can be done by `@AutoConfigureBefore` and `@AutoConfigureAfter` annotations to define where this autoconfiguration has to be initialized.

Another annotation `@AutoConfigureOrder` is the Spring Boot equivalent of the `@Order` annotation could also be used to change the order (since @Order does not work for autoconfigurations).

If you check your favourite starter's source code, you will see these order changing annotations are often added to the class.